# What exactly does the verb move mean here?

Tags: word-meaning

> The teacher moved the students to action.

I found out that the word action is a noun.  Then, what exactly does the verb move mean here then?   It cannot mean cause for action is a noun.   Could you help me clarify it?   Thanks.

Comment: This definition should be in the dictionary, [see #14 at dictionary.com: *to prompt, actuate, or impel to some action:*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/move?s=t).   But I understand if "move" has so many definitions it's hard to keep track.

Comment: https://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/move+to+action

Comment: The legal definition does not apply here.

Comment: Yes, to move someone to action, is to impel or prompt.

Answer (score 3):

When we move others to act, we often do so by speaking in a convincing or rousing way of the need for action.  A speech can move some members in the audience to act.

In this specific context (where a person moves a person) the word **move**  means to bring others to do something, especially by persuasive speech or oratory.

In general contexts, the word **move** when used in the following patterns simply means "to bring or cause someone to do something".

The patterns are as follows:

Someone|something **moves** someone **to** {bare infinitive}

> The music was so lively they were moved to **dance**. <sup>verb</sup>
>
> Their leader's extreme positions moved some members of his own party to **speak out**.<sup>verb</sup>
>
> The rent increase moved the tenants to **complain**. <sup>verb</sup>

Someone|something **moves** someone  **to** {noun that expresses some action or emotional state}

> In the final scene of the play, the actor moved the audience to **tears.** <sup>noun</sup>
>
> The trio's slapstick antics moved the audience to **laughter**. <sup>noun</sup>
>
> When they heard how their friends had been mistreated, they were moved to **anger**.<sup>noun</sup>